# Using Javascript to get only currentSrc of all array items of Xpath query.

Tags: javascript, arrays, xpath, attributes, google-chrome-devtools

Using Chrome Dev Tools console,  I have xpath   $x("//img[contains(@src, 'https://')]")

to get image links from this website: https://www.etsy.com/market/happiness_bracelet. 
It is returning 164 results in the array, but I only need the currentSrc property of each result in the array. How would I do that through JavaScript?

I tried: var x = $x("//img[contains(@src, 'https://')]")

for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
    console.log(x[i]);

but it is giving me class, src, and alt values. I only need src values, so that's why I want to get only currentSrc of each result in the array.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `x[i].currentSrc`:

```
var x = $x("//img[contains(@src, 'https://')]");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { console.log(x[i].currentSrc); };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reach src attribute in current element,

```
for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) { 
   console.log(x[i].src); 
}
```